# How to get array of random doubles in C?

Tags: arrays, c, double

I want to generate an array with random doubles but get an "Segmentation Fault" instead of the result. When I use the same code but replace `double` with `float`, everything works. How is that?
Code below works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int N = 1048576;

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    float B[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        B[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    printf("B[0]=%lf\n", B[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

And code below gives me segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int N = 1048576;

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    double B[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        B[i] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    printf("B[0]=%lf\n", B[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm a noob in C, so any detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide the error log.

Comment: `double B[N];` that is ~8MB, quite a big bunch of data to put on the stack.

Comment: In most C implementations, stack space is limited. Inside a function, `double B[N];` uses space on the stack, in typical C implementations. Use `double *B = malloc(N * sizeof *B);` to get dynamically allocated memory instead. (And, to be safe, test `B` after to ensure it is not a null pointer.) Incidentally, you are probably using macOS, because the default primary stack sizes on Windows and Linux are 1 MiB and 2 MiB, so the `float` case would have failed as well. The default on macOS is 8 MiB, enough for 1,048,576 `float` elements but not `double` elements.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't  accurate to say it is error. The program compiles, but instead of result in format B[0]=<some_double> i simply get "Segmentation fault"

Comment: Note, that your "random doubles" are not that random. Your algorithm will only chose from a subset of (approximately) rational numbers containing RAND_MAX elements.

Answer (score 3):

You want to allocate the memory with malloc instead of using the stack.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  srand(time(NULL));

  size_t N = 1234567ull;
  double *array = malloc(sizeof(double) * N);

  if (array == NULL) {
      perror("array allocation");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  
  for (size_t i = 0ull; i < N; i++) {
    array[i] = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
  }

  printf("%f\n", array[0]);
  free(array);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why use `1234567ull` and `0ull`? `size_t` may have a smaller type than `unsigned long long`, forcing the constant type is useless and makes the code less readable.

Comment: `size_t` is essentially always `unsigned long long` on x64.

Comment: As for why I used it, I'm used to having to specify exactly what numbers due to compiler warnings(errors).

Comment: `size_t i = 0ull;` should not generate a warning, but I understand where you come from, probably too much Misra on your plate :) Do you intentionally use `%lf` instead of `%f` in `printf`?

Comment: yeah... misra is really fun... but uh `%lf` was just what I remembered from the top of my head how to print doubles

Comment: `%lf` is necessary to scan floating point values into `double` variables. The `l` is ignored by `printf` as `float` values are implicitly converted to `double` when passed as vararg function arguments.

Comment: ah right, I'll edit the answer then

Answer (score 2):

You define an array `float B[N];` with automatic storage that is quite large (4MB), you are lucky the stack is large enough on your system to accommodate such an object.  Conversely changing the type to `double` also doubles the size of this local object, which seems definitely too large to allocate on the stack, invoking undefined behavior as you observe.

It is recommended to allocate large arrays from the heap using `malloc` or `calloc`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

size_t N = 1048576;

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    double *B = malloc(sizeof(*B) * N);
    if (B == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate B\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        B[i] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    printf("B[0]=%f\n", B[0]);

    free(B);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `calloc` is slower than `malloc` you're essentially overwriting it a second later anyway so it's unnecessary.

Comment: You have a point. But in this particular case, allocating an 8MB block with `calloc()` should be just as fast as `malloc()` if the allocation system can and does assume that the OS returns newly mmapped pages with all bits zero.

Comment: Yea, probably won't make any significant difference here.

Answer (score 0):

The array has automatic storage duration and is too big for allocation with the automatic storage duration.

Either declare it in the file scope or with the storage specifier `static` within the function main to make it with static storage duration. Or allocate the array dynamically.